# Is there a way to bring Strings together in java apart from StringBuffer and toString?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, split, tostring, stringbuffer

```
String Fehlerspeicher_ist = "Fehlerspeicher";
String Fehlerspeicher_soll = "20_Fehlerspeicher";
String lines[] = temp.split("\n");

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

for (int i=0; i< lines.length; i++)
{
    if (lines[i].contains(Fehlerspeicher_ist) && lines[i+1].contains("Fehler gespeichert")) 
    {
       lines[i].replace(Fehlerspeicher_ist, Fehlerspeicher_soll);
       result.append(lines[i]);
       result.append("\r\n");
    }
}

temp = result.toString();
```

This `toString` is unfortunately throwing a **NullPointerException**. I think I have that problem, because `toString` method is already used in different parts of the code. Is there any other way to bring these `String arrays` together? Something like reverse of `split` method which could be used instead of `StringBuffer` or `toString`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This code throws an error because this line: `if (lines[i].contains(Fehlerspeicher_ist)&&lines[i+1].contains("Fehler gespeichert"))` tries to access `lines[i+1]` which for the last element will be outside the array size.

Comment: 'temp' doesn't exist in that code snippet?! Undefined cannot resolve symbol...

Comment: @NorbertRadyk Yeah, agreed -- however wouldn't that be an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: I bet you it is not the StringBuffer throwing the NullPointerException. Show the stacktrace.

Comment: The StringBuffer cannot be throwing the NPE - you explicitly initialise it! Stack trace please -- my bet is that `lines` (undefined in the code snipped but I presume it's defined in the actual code otherwise it won't compile!) is null.

Comment: Apart from that it will not replace anything until you specify `lines[i] = lines[i].replace(Fehlerspeicher_ist, Fehlerspeicher_soll);`

Comment: Your code also kind of suggests that you are unaware of the fact that `String`s are immutable in Java.

Comment: have you debugged your codes?

Comment: Please don't use `StringBuffer`, it was replaced by `StringBuilder` ten years ago.

Comment: The Stack Trace looks like this: Note that when I delete toString methode from the code above everything works fine.

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at de.beg.diagradb.bus.parser.DiagraTxtGrParser.main(DiagraTxtGrParser.java:196)**

Comment: What is on line 196 please?

Comment: @Kent Nope but only line that makes a problem is the line with toString

Comment: @AlSweetman    Line 196 would be this System.out.println(measure.toString());

Comment: So you're calling `measure.toString();` which you say is failing -- that's different to the code example above which is calling `result.toString();`

Comment: @regardless then debug, set breakpoint on that line, then you can see what is null and why you got NPE

Comment: OK it fundamentally breaks down like this.  The code you presented above cannot throw a NPE, unless you're overriding the toString() method somehwere (some kind of MOP) but I presume you're not.  The Stacktrace you presented is for a different code snippet( variable name `measure` vs variable name `result`).  The code above, if one "presumes" a variable for `temp` [`temp = "aa";` or some such] works without throwing an NPE.

Comment: @AlSweetman the complete code has more than 15000 lines and many more classes which work properly. What I did above was a small change in that which leaded to that failure. That's why I guessed that it's because of this toString and I tried without it. The code worked again. However I gotta bring these Strings together again so I can make the code work.

Comment: Sorry, @regardless, I don't really think I can provide much more to this. Hope you get something sorted.

Comment: @PeterLawrey tried. Stringbuffer or builder, that doesn't help at all.

Comment: @regardless there is no way the code you have shown is throwing an NPE.  If there is an issue, it is not in the code you have shown.

Answer (score 1):

If the `toString` method call is throwing a `NullPointerException`, it is because the reference on which you're calling it is `null`. There can't be any other reason. See why it's `null` and fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Because when i delete toString methode, the code does work with the other parts (which have also toString methode inside) except it's not changed as the way I want.